# ffmpeg - position is always shifted

Tags: ffmpeg, video

My app idea is to take a video with mobile, overlay an image or gif on top of the video, then combine all of them together.

The problem is that the position of the overlayed image/gif is always shifted from the position I choose on screen. I think it is related to aspect ratio but I don't know how to fix it.

The problem gets worse when I add two or more images/gifs at the same time.

Here is my code for one overlay:

```
[-i, mobileVideo.mp4, -ignore_loop, 0, -i, cheaf.gif, -b:v, 1M, -filter_complex, [1:v]scale=60.0:60.0[ovrl1]; [0:v][ovrl1]overlay=overlay=54.71990411931819:225.6267755681818:shortest=1:format=auto[out] , -map, [out], -qscale:v, 2, /data/user/0/com.q8intouch.hareem/cache/JFkhb.mp4].
```

These overlay values are the values on the screen.

Here is the log:

```
/flutter-ffmpeg(24748): Running FFmpeg with arguments: [-i, /data/user/0/com.q8intouch.hareem/cache/REC9127166347200678375.mp4, -ignore_loop, 0, -i, /data/user/0/com.q8intouch.hareem/cache/1622464370-cheaf.gif, -b:v, 1M, -filter_complex, [1:v]scale=60.0:60.0[ovrl1]; [0:v][ovrl1]overlay=54.71990411931819:225.6267755681818:shortest=1:format=auto[out] , -map, [out], -qscale:v, 2, /data/user/0/com.q8intouch.hareem/cache/z3Xt0.mp4].
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): ffmpeg version v4.4-dev-416
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):  Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):   built with Android (6454773 based on r365631c2) clang version 9.0.8 (https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/llvm-project 98c855489587874b2a325e7a516b99d838599c6f) (based on LLVM 9.0.8svn)
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):   configuration: --cross-prefix=i686-linux-android- --sysroot=/files/android-sdk/ndk/21.3.6528147/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --prefix=/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-x86/ffmpeg --pkg-config=/usr/bin/pkg-config --enable-version3 --arch=i686 --cpu=i686 --cc=i686-linux-android24-clang --cxx=i686-linux-android24-clang++ --extra-libs='-L/home/taner/Projects/mobile-ffmpeg/prebuilt/android-x86/cpu-features/lib -lndk_compat' --target-os=android --disable-neon --disable-asm --disable-inline-asm --enable-cross-compile --enable-pic --enable-jni --enable-optimizations --enable-swscale --enable-shared --enable-v4l2-m2m --disable-outdev=fbdev --disable-indev=fbdev --enable-small --disable-openssl --disable-xmm-clobber-test --disable-debug --enable-lto --disable-neon-clobber-test --disable-programs --disable-postproc --disable-doc --disable-htmlpages --disable-manpages --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --disable-static --disable-sndio --disable-schannel --disable-securetransport --disable-xlib --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --disable-videotoolbox --disable-audiotoolbox --disable-appkit --disable-alsa --disable-cuda --disable-cuvid --disable-nvenc --disable-vaapi --disable-vdpau --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libass --enable-iconv --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libxml2 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libshine --enable-libspeex --enable-libwavpack --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libilbc --enable-libopus --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libaom --enable-libtwolame --disable-sdl2 --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-zlib --enable-mediacodec
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):   libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):   libavcodec     58. 96.100 / 58. 96.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):   libavformat    58. 48.100 / 58. 48.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):   libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):   libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):   libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):   libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/data/user/0/com.q8intouch.hareem/cache/REC9127166347200678375.mp4':
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):   Metadata:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     major_brand     :
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): mp42
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     minor_version   :
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 0
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     compatible_brands:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): isommp42
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     creation_time   :
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 2021-07-02T13:02:18.000000Z
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     com.android.version:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 8.1.0
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):   Duration:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 00:00:03.05
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): , start:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 0.000000
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): , bitrate:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 104 kb/s
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     Stream #0:0
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): (eng)
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): : Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 320x240, 88 kb/s
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): , SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): ,
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 15.10 fps,
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 28.92 tbr,
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 90k tbn,
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 180k tbc
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):  (default)
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     Metadata:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):       rotate          :
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 90
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):       creation_time   :
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 2021-07-02T13:02:18.000000Z
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):       handler_name    :
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): VideoHandle
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     Side data:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     Stream #0:1
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): (eng)
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): : Audio: amr_nb (samr / 0x726D6173), 8000 Hz, mono, flt, 12 kb/s
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):  (default)
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     Metadata:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):       creation_time   :
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 2021-07-02T13:02:18.000000Z
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):       handler_name    :
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): SoundHandle
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): Input #1, gif, from '/data/user/0/com.q8intouch.hareem/cache/1622464370-cheaf.gif':
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):   Metadata:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     comment         :
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): Resized on https://ezgif.com/resize
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):   Duration:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 00:00:03.56
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): , start:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 0.000000
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): , bitrate:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 748 kb/s
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     Stream #1:0
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): : Video: gif, bgra, 250x250
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): ,
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 25 fps,
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 25 tbr,
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 100 tbn,
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 100 tbc
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): Stream mapping:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):   Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):   Stream #1:0 (gif) -> scale
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):   overlay
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):  -> Stream #0:0 (mpeg4)
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=-577014:32:22.77 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s speed=N/A
W/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): [graph 0 input from stream 1:0 @ 0x6ae849e0] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
W/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): [graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x6ae85ca0] sws_param option is deprecated and ignored
W/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): [swscaler @ 0x4994e000] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to bgra.
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): Output #0, mp4, to '/data/user/0/com.q8intouch.hareem/cache/z3Xt0.mp4':
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):   Metadata:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     major_brand     :
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): mp42
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     minor_version   :
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 0
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     compatible_brands:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): isommp42
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     com.android.version:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 8.1.0
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     encoder         :
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): Lavf58.48.100
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     Stream #0:0
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): : Video: mpeg4 (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p, 240x320 [SAR 1:1 DAR 3:4], q=2-31, 1000 kb/s
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): ,
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 28.92 fps,
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 11104 tbn,
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 28.92 tbc
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):  (default)
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     Metadata:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):       encoder         :
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): Lavc58.96.100 mpeg4
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):     Side data:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): cpb:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/1000000 buffer size: 0
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): vbv_delay: N/A
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=2.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=3911.1kbits/s speed=0.000168x
E/AudioTrack(24748): Discontinuity detected [expected 2533046000, got 2534272000]
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): frame=    1 fps=0.9 q=2.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=3911.1kbits/s speed=8.5e-05x
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): frame=   37 fps= 23 q=2.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.24 bitrate=   0.3kbits/s dup=35 drop=0 speed=0.759x
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): frame=   46 fps= 20 q=2.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.55 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s dup=38 drop=0 speed=0.693x
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): frame=   50 fps= 18 q=2.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.69 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s dup=38 drop=0 speed=0.607x
E/AudioTrack(24748): Discontinuity detected [expected 2536092000, got 2537318000]
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): frame=   51 fps= 14 q=2.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.72 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s dup=38 drop=0 speed=0.481x
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): frame=   58 fps= 14 q=2.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.97 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s dup=38 drop=0 speed=0.479x
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): frame=   67 fps= 14 q=2.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.28 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s dup=38 drop=0 speed=0.488x
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): frame=   73 fps= 14 q=2.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.49 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s dup=39 drop=0 speed=0.47x
E/AudioTrack(24748): Discontinuity detected [expected 2539138000, got 2540364000]
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): frame=   78 fps= 13 q=2.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.66 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s dup=42 drop=0 speed=0.456x
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): frame=   84 fps= 13 q=2.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.87 bitrate=   0.1kbits/s dup=42 drop=0 speed=0.452x
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): frame=   88 fps= 13 q=2.0 Lsize=     110kB time=00:00:03.00 bitrate= 298.7kbits/s dup=42 drop=0 speed=0.445x
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): video:108kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead:
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748): 1.131698%
I/mobile-ffmpeg(24748):
D/flutter-ffmpeg(24748): FFmpeg exited with rc: 0
```

Comment: Just FYI, it would be better to have a proper ffmpeg *command line* example that illustrates your problem. That way people can almost directly run your command and see the results for themselves. On top of that programming questions are off topic here.

Comment: Be aware that the overlay filter places the upper left corner of the image/video to be overlaid onto the co-ordinates you provide. Are you expecting it to be centered instead?

Comment: @llogan  when I feed ffmpeg with theses co-ordinates I expect the image/gif will appear accurately at the same position shown on my screen .. but what happens is that it shifts some -or many- pixels away .. I don't understand how ffmpeg coordinates system works, but I think this shift happens due to difference between aspect ratios ffmpeg use and mobile screen has.

Comment: @llogan  any advice sir ?

Comment: `mobileVideo.mp4` is 320x240. `mobileVideo.mp4` needs to be the same width and height as the mobile screen. I doubt the mobile screen is 320x240. Too small.